# Sending property through router not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly, this is my router view definition:

```
{
  path: '/page',
  name: 'page',
  component: Page,
  props: true,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true}
},
```

Then I access the view like this:

```
self.$router.push({ name: 'page', params: {stuff: true }})
```

This is my page component:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    {{ stuff }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'Page',
  data() {
    return {
      stuff: false
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

It looks like `stuff` property is not being set to `true`, its always `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our code will pass `stuff` as component props, not component's data

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
    {{ stuff }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'Page',
  props: ['stuff']
}
</script>
```

In [document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode):

> When `props` is set to `true`, the `route.params` will be set as the
>   component props

Comment: Ahh you are correct, I was using data instead actual prop, thanks